# AForge.Video - Camera not centered

Tags: vb.net, camera, aforge

I am using AForge.Video to use camera in my laptop.
But why the video captured by camera is not centered?

Below is my code:

```
 Dim videoDevices As FilterInfoCollection
 Dim videoSource As VideoCaptureDevice
 videoDevices = New FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)
 videoSource = New VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices(0).MonikerString)
 AddHandler videoSource.NewFrame, AddressOf Me.video_NewFrame

  Sub video_NewFrame(sender As Object,
        eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)

        Dim bitmap As Bitmap
        Try

            bitmap = eventArgs.Frame
            If Not bitmap Is Nothing Then


                PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(bitmap.Clone(), Bitmap)
                PictureBox1.Refresh()
            End If

        Catch

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe i understand what you mean by "Camera not centered" but i know that it is better to use AForge Clone() to grab the frame inside video_NewFrame event handler

```
bitmap = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(eventArgs.Frame);
```

and make sure that your PictureBox1 sizemode property is set to "StretchImage"